# the application on android cant run

Tags: java, android

why??

> [2011-08-26 14:57:48 - Front] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=mpos.gui.ask/.Front } from null (pid=5918, uid=2000) requires null

my manifest

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mpos.gui.ask" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Front" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="Login"></activity>
        <activity android:name="FtpList"></activity>
        <activity android:name="LoginMpos"></activity>
        <activity android:name="MenuMpos"></activity>
        <activity android:name="PilihCabang"></activity>
        <activity android:name="FormTransaksi"></activity>
        <activity android:name="SdhTrans"></activity>
        <activity android:name="BuatTransaksi"></activity>
        <activity android:name="LihatTrans"></activity>
        <activity android:name="CekStok"></activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

</manifest
```

i'm pasive english :D
anyone can help
thanks be4

Comment: When does this error happen? When you try to start another acitivty from the Front activity?

Comment: can you provide more information from the error stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing network status in your application too? If so I think you need to include permission for this too in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with flutter, I had a similar error that was solved by adding `android:exported="true"` to the main activity, so in your case it seems to be here

```
<activity android:name=".Front" android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="true">
```